# Uploading a image with Alamofire in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to upload an image with Alamofire, however it does not seem to upload.

```
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "data", fileName: "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        multipartFormData.append(operaID.data, withName: "id")
    },
                     to: URL_CORDINATE)
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print("Upload image response:", response.result.value)
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print("Error while uploading image:", encodingError)
        }
```

I'm expecting to see the image upload, however there seems to be something wrong with the body (I should pass the img and id in the body not as parameters!)

It does however work in Postman: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0mUd.png

Comment: Is there any error output?

Comment: No error in the output

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
Alamofire.upload(
                multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                    multipartFormData.append(imgData!, withName: "img", fileName: "jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            },
                to: UPLOAD_IMAGE_URL,
                encodingCompletion: { (encodingResult) -> Void in
                    switch encodingResult {
                    case .success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.responseJSON { response in
                            let result = response.data
                            do {
                                print("success")
                            }catch {
                                print("error")
                            }
                        }
                    case .failure(let encodingError):
                        print(encodingError)

                    }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first look it's missing the HTTP method: `.post`, and the mimeType should be `"image/jpeg"`, not `"image/jpg"`.

See this:

```
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "data", fileName: "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        multipartFormData.append(operaID.data, withName: "id")
    },
    to: YOUR_URL_HERE,
    method: .post,
    encodingCompletion: { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print("Upload image response:", response.result.value)
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print("Error while uploading image:", encodingError)
        }
    })
```

Is there any server log indicating error? Can you add breakpoints to the server code and run it on localhost to check what you have in your controller?

In case the server endpoint is http put this in your `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: I've tried making the changes you suggested, however it still seems not to be working (when I print the result given by Alamofire I get: "CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds"). Not sure why!

Comment: What is your url? Is it http or https? This error can occur with http server endpoints.

Comment: http://artaugmentedreality.com/api/postpreview/ with "img" (image) and "id" (e.g. 44) in the body.

Comment: I added the domain to the list in info.plist of supported HTTP domains, but I still get the same error! :(

Comment: How is your `Info.plist` look like? Extended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            if let img = image, let imageData = img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.6) {
                multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: imageName, fileName: "temp.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            }
            for (key, value) in parameter ?? [:] {
                if value is String || value is Int {
                    multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
            }
        }, to: url, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _ , _ ):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                    if response.response?.statusCode == 200
                    {
                        if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: response.result.value!, options: .prettyPrinted) {
                            print("Response: \n",String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "nil")
                        }
                        success(response.result.value! as AnyObject)
                    }else
                    {
                        let res = response.result.value! as AnyObject
                        let msg = res["Message"] as? String
                        if msg != nil
                        {
                            failure(msg!)
                        }else
                        {
                            failure("")
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                failure(encodingError.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
```